# rxjs: can I subscribe before defining observable?

Tags: rxjs

I am new to rxjs (temporarily helping another project), so I feel like I must be missing something in the documentation. Here is a simplified version of what I'm working on, which involves integrating with an existing event bus:

```
function thirdPartyStuff( callback ) {
  for ( let i = 0; i < history.length; i++ ) {
    callback( history[ i ] ); // gets called now if event history exists
  }
  this.callbacks.push( callback ); // will be called later when more happen
}

function makeObservable() {
  return new Observable( observer => {
    this.thirdPartyStuff( function( thing ) {
      observer.next( thing );
    } );
  } ).pipe(
    share()
  );
}

function runMyCode() {
  this.monitor = this.makeObservable();
  return this.monitor.subscribe( thing => console.log( thing ) );
}
```

My issue is, if the `history` has stuff in it, `observer.next` gets called before the `subscribe` does. I have solved this problem like so:

```
function makeObservable() {
  return new Observable( observer => {
    setTimeout( () => {  // delay observer.next until subscribe exists
      this.thirdPartyStuff( function( thing ) {
        observer.next( thing );
      } );
    } );
  } ).pipe(
    share()
  );
}
```

What I want to know is, does a better way exist, or am I really stuck with using `setTimeout`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

set up your function like so:

```
makeObservable() {
  const rs = new ReplaySubject();
  const obs = new Observable( observer => {
    this.thirdPartyStuff( function( thing ) {
      observer.next( thing );
    });
  } ).pipe(
    share()
  );

  obs.subscribe(rs);
  return rs;
}
```

now the subscroption happens immediately as the function is called, and any subscriber gets either the last emitted value right away or the next emitted value when it arrives.

Comment: Neither of them are working because I need the full history to be sent through, not just the last one. Is there an "all" replay? (I mean neither this nor your first answer of "shareReplay")

Comment: just don't feed an argument to replay subject, this causes the replay count to be infinite.

Comment: you can do the same with shareReplay. Out of curiosity, did that solution work? I changed my answer because I didn't think shareReplay would start caching emissions until at least one subscriber existed, but i could be mistaken if it worked at all.

Comment: I actually used shareReplay because it works and is simpler -- I saw your first answer before you edited it and tried it out. I just knew with so many operators in rxjs there must be something to do this, so I am not surprised there are at least two. I am already a fan of rxjs after two days experience because it is so versatile.